# How to create a 3d model with camera ou photos?

Tags: android, iphone, 3d, 3d-modelling, 3d-model

I wanna create a mobile app that uses a 3d model from a face.
I want create the model with photos or camera.
Any suggestions???
Thanks.

Comment: Not to sound discouraging or like "that guy" but this is a huge undertaking. From my understanding, you want to take a number of photos and link them together into a 3d model. If you have the mind to logically blend that together by yourself, more power to you, but man does that sound like a headache. First things first, look up on getting an image from the camera. Once you do that, it is time to start logically breaking it down (best of luck to you on that end). Here is a start on camera imaging http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know how to get the camera image. My problem is that in the project I´m creating I need to have a precise 3d model of a face. I wanna know if there is any API or good algorithm to create them.

Comment: Was my understanding correct? Are you trying to blend a number of 2d images into a 3d model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this old question looking for the same thing, but I did manage to find a program called "Autodesk 123D Catch" here:  http://www.123dapp.com/catch that seems to do what you need.

If you had to write something yourself (the horror), I'd start with the OpenCV library; they have some strong 2D code, and some loosely related 3d code that may give you a foothold: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html